# How to find the display name of a user in Firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

When using Firebase in an iOS app (Swift 3) what is the way to get the displayname of a user knowing her/his uid?

I know how to find the displayname of the current user. But I want it for any user.

Comment: Short answer: you can't! For an alternative, see the nice answer by @kunalkamble below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are trying to look inside default auth record then it is only accessible for that user, if you want to access data for all users then in signup process you need to create users node and store readable data there so that is all the time accessible.

```
users
  $uid1
     metadata
        name: 'John Doe'
        avatar: 'image-url.jpg'
  $uid3
     metadata
        name: 'Rick Ross'
        avatar: 'image-url.jpg'
```

you can define rule for user metadata, and can make it public and can be access any time.

Comment: Thanks. I need to look into that "users node" thing then. I hope it is well documented inside the Firebase documentation.

Comment: Do you have any particular URL in mind, that I could go to and check how this works?

Comment: I have a question related to your suggestion. Are you thinking of some API in particular that I need to use when running this:
FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: email, password: passWord) {...} ?
Or do you mean that I should create by hand a node in the Realtime Database to store the information I will want to have for any other user to access? Same in the case of a user changing her/his displayname. I will also have to maintain my node information separately? Or is there a better way?